# Why is database access (SQL Server) slower on Windows 7?

Tags: sql-server, windows-7

We use SQL Server 2000 to store results from our test equipment. We have installed our test software on Windows XP machines and do not have any problems with the time it takes to query from and write to the database.

When we recently installed a Windows 7 machine the database access appears to be taking 20 to 100 times as long. We connect to SQL Server using a COM interface passing a connection string that holds the server name, login ID and default database:

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;
Persist Security Info=False;
User ID={Login name};
Initial Catalog={Database name};
Data Source={Server name}
```

I have tried using a .net database interface but this does not provide any significant improvement in speed.

Is SQL Server database access from Windows 7 just much slower that Windows XP or is there any way to increase the performance of our code?

**Extra detail**

We have SQL Server 2000 running on Windows 2003 server. This is our production database that stores test results from over 40 test stations. We have plans to upgrade to SQL Server 2005 but this is dependant on another project that will not be complete for approx 6 months. The client PC (the one accessing the database) is Windows 7.

I have tested using a Windows 7 client PC accessing SQL Server 2005 running on Windows 2003 server and found similar results.

As a quick test I have run a SELECT query 100 times on both Windows 7 and Windows XP with Windows 7 taking approx 30 seconds and Windows XP less than 1 second to complete. This has been repeated with both SQL server 2000 and 2003 amd the same difference is seen.

Comment: Is the 2000 instance installed on Win7 or are you connecting to a remote instance?

Comment: The SQL 2000 instance is running on a Windows 2003 server

Comment: Your quick test with 100 SELECT queries - does single test include connection time or do you use opened connection? In first case I'd suspect DNS problem, which causes connection attempt to take unuasally long time.

Comment: The quick test includes connection time, the same test runs faster on WinXP than Win7 so that would suggest Win7 handles DNS queries differently. Just tested using IP address which is much faster.

Comment: It may actually not be DNS, but order of SQL providers. In LAN there are differet options used - Named Pipes and TCP/IP; DNS is related only to TCP/IP. Run cliconfig from command line - there you can change provider order (at least on XP and Vista; I've no W7 present here).

Comment: Checking cliconfg on WinXP and Win7, both have all protocols disabled. Enabling any of the protocols has no noticeable effect on the speed.

Answer (score 4):

You're using an ancient version of SQL Server on a new version of Windows.

[Per this MS bulletin,](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlreleaseservices/archive/2009/10/23/sql-server-on-windows-7-and-windows-server-2008-r2.aspx) SQL Server 2000 is expressly not supported on Win7.

Upgrade your SQL Server version.

Comment: The SQL 2000 instance is running on a Windows 2003 server. The client PC is running Win7 which is accessing the SQL databases.

Answer (score 1):

Still if you are facing the issue, please see blow resolution:

### Root Cause

The issue which we were seeing on Win7 VDIs could be due to the Network hardware device connected with the machine. If TCP/IP scaling is  not supported by the network device then the performance will be slow.

### Solution

Disable auto tuning level of the TCP. Please follow below steps:
1)  Open command Prompt with admin right (Run as Admin)
2)  Type “netsh interface tcp set global autotuninglevel=disabled”
3)  After running above command restart the machine.

For other information on this command, visit  link “http://support.microsoft.com/kb/935400”

Answer (score 0):

This problem may be caused by the LLMNR protocol which is a new name resolution protocol for both IPv4 & IPv6 that is used on Vista, Win7 and some servers.

So:

- You can turn off LLMNR protocol over GPEdit.msc
  ([Link to PDF - how](http://www.schoolleader.com/Documentation/Disabling_LLMNR_Causing_Slow_Networks.pdf))

or

- Use fully qualified domain name (FQDN) (then LLMNR is not used)